# Merge field for image not displaying in Word 2007 using livedocx and php

Tags: php, word-2007, livedocx

I'm trying to add a server side image uploaded from a user form to a Word document that gets generated using LiveDocx.

My word template looks like this.

```
«image:photo»
```

AKA

```
{ MERGEFIELD image:photo \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

My php looks like this.

```
$mailMerge = new Zend_Service_LiveDocx_MailMerge();
$mailMerge->uploadImage($this->logo_path);
$mailMerge->assign('image:photo', $this->logo_path);
```

I just get a blank area where the image should be. My other merge fields are working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize that LiveDocx stores only the name of the file to be referenced. I found this out using:

```
$mailMerge->listImages();
```

The format came back like this:

```
array
0 => array
  'filename' => string 'directory_logo.png' (length=18)
  'fileSize' => int 12829
  'createTime' => int 1352835686
  'modifyTime' => int 1352835686
```

So the template file was fine with this format:

```
«image:photo»
```

AKA

```
{ MERGEFIELD image:photo \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

But my php needed to look like this:

```
$mailMerge->uploadImage($this->logo_path);
$mailMerge->assign('image:photo', $this->logo_file);
```

My full working code looks like this:

```
$mailMerge = new Zend_Service_LiveDocx_MailMerge();
$mailMerge->setUsername($username)
  ->setPassword($password);
$mailMerge->setLocalTemplate($template_path . '/service_template.docx');
$mailMerge->uploadImage($this->logo_path);
$mailMerge->assign('image:photo', 'directory_logo.png');
$mailMerge->createDocument();
$document = $mailMerge->retrieveDocument('docx');
file_put_contents($this->config->livedocx->document . '/' . $this->prefs['serverid'] . '/service_directory.docx', $document);
$mailMerge->deleteImage('directory_logo.png');
```